# Return "Error" if no match found by regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string:

```
link = "http://www.this_is_my_perfect_url.com/blah_blah/blah_blah?=trololo"
```

And I have a function which return the domain name from that url or if it not found, returns `''`:

```
def get_domain(url):
    domain_regex = re.compile("\:\/\/(.*?)\/|$")
    return re.findall(domain_regex, str(url))[0].replace('www.', '')

get_domain(link)
```

returned result:

```
this_is_my_perfect_url.com
```

`|$` returns `''` if regex matches nothing.

Is there a way to implement the default value `Error` inside regex so I do not have to do any check inside the fuction?

So if `link = "there_is_no_domain_in_here"` then the fuction returns `Error` instead of `''`.

Comment: No, you cannot set anything within regex, it only returns what it finds in the input text. You must return `Error` in code.

Comment: As mentioned by WiktorStribiżew you need to check this outside your regex matching logic @milka1117 as per my answer below

Comment: You mean "return the literal string 'Error'" not "raise an Error/Exception"?

Comment: As side note: please consider if returning `"Error"` is good solution in your case - what if your url is `http://www.error.com` ? If for some reason you do not want to raise error you might return `None`, which is commonly used in Python for saying *nothing*

Comment: Yes, @Daweo is phrasing better the point I was trying to make. It is not Pythonic to return error conditions as strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, you cannot set anything in regex to do that for you, but you can check if the output returned by `re.findall` after applying the extra formatting is empty or not, and if it is empty, which means that no matches were found, return `Error`

```
import re
link = "http://www.this_is_my_perfect_url.com/blah_blah/blah_blah?=trololo"

def get_domain(url):
    domain_regex = re.compile("\:\/\/(.*?)\/|$")

    #Get regex matches into a list after data massaging
    matches = re.findall(domain_regex, str(url))[0].replace('www.', '')

    #Return the match or Error if output is empty
    return matches or 'Error'

print(get_domain(link))
print(get_domain('there_is_no_domain_in_here'))
```

The output will be

```
this_is_my_perfect_url.com
Error
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to put my two cents in - the lazy quantifier (`.*?`) in combination with an alternation (`|$`) is very ineffective. You can [**vastly ameliorate your expression**](https://regex101.com/r/0W7vgC/1/) to:

```
://[^/]+
```

Additionally, as of `Python 3.8` you could use the walrus operator as in

```
if (m := re.search("://[^/]+", your_string)) is not None:
    # found sth.
else
    return "Error"
```

And no - with regular expressions *alone* you cannot get sth. out of a string which is not there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

why not use urlparse to get domain?

```py
# env python 2
# import urlparse
# python 3
from urllib.parse import urlparse


def get_domain(url):
    parsed_uri = urlparse(url)
    domain = parsed_uri.netloc
    return domain or "ERROR"

url = 'there_is_no_domain_in_here'
print(get_domain(url))
```